# why do we use ginger and garlic in meat curry?

Tags: meat, indian-cuisine, garlic, ginger, pakistani-cuisine

Garlic and ginger are a staple in South Asian meat (chicken, beef, goat, lamb, duck, etc.) curries.

I am just wondering, why.

What attributes of garlic and ginger made them essential ingredients for meat curry?

What do they actually improve in meat? Do they remove meaty smell?

Comment: Can you give some indication of why you are expecting a reason beyond "because they taste good"?

Comment: Possibly related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/14249/67

Comment: I'm afraid you're asking an opinion-based question, then.  Good questions for SA need to be ones where a verifiable answer can be given.  "Why does cuisine X use ingredient Y" is not determinative.

Comment: @FuzzyChef “Because of the taste” would make a fine, non-opinion-based answer. If the question had been “why do we put baking powder in biscuits” would you have called that opinion-based? And how is the OP supposed to know the difference before they have their answer?

Comment: @Sneftel in cooking, 99% of ingredients and pretty much all combinations are used because of taste (baking is somewhat more complicated). I don't see much value for the site in having this kind of question repeated for different ingredient pairings. My preference would be for people who ask such a question to have done some minimal research to indicate that there might be something more to the pairing than the default. I won't mod-hammer this after the community reopened it, but I will add a post notice, hopefully it will help hold back the opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ginger can *potentially* [tenderize meat](http://livestockscience.in/wp-content/uploads/ginger-meat.pdf). But the ginger in curries is generally cooked before even adding the meat, which would [destroy the enzymes](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/30084/58067) responsible for doing anything like that.

It's commonly held that that ginger (and, less commonly, garlic) [mask the smell of raw meat](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5055890/). It would be difficult to draw a principled distinction between "A masks the aroma of B" and "A and B taste good together": As far as I know, ginger and garlic do not chemically react with the undesirable flavor compounds in meat. And in something like a curry, you'd expect the other flavorings (particularly turmeric and cumin, common in curries) to suffice for that even if the ginger and garlic weren't there.*

Finally, the ginger/garlic combination is found in many Asian cuisines: South Indian, North Indian, Thai, Cantonese, Korean, etc., often in meat-free dishes. So whatever *other* reasons one might have for using these ingredients, clearly they're widely considered to simply taste good together, including in meat curry.

* I'd note that [one published paper](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/abs/10.1086/420058) takes an evolutionary perspective and argues that covering up the aroma of foul-smelling meat would not be a reason that people use strong-smelling flavorings, simply because *eating foul-smelling meat is a bad idea even if you cover up the smell*. I'm not particularly convinced by their reasoning, though: it seems rather hastily teleological.

Comment: There was a flag noting that the comment section became quite off-topic. I deleted the comments; whatever the truth, it won't be likely found in this comment line. Maybe History Stackexchange or Politics Stackexchange will take a related question, if it contains some research effort.